# Next.js How do you set the alias?

Tags: typescript, next.js

this is my configuration

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U79tY.png)

but Next.js gave me this warning

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JShPT.png)

Comment: Please make sure to post code and errors as text directly to the question (and [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551)), and [format them appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Also, are you sure the `Layout` component is under the `components` folder?

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. the problem has been solved

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code and errors as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry. This is my first question on StackOverflow

Here's how I solved it:
Since my Next.JS is the TypeScript project
so, my project has tsconfig.json

1. Add baseUrl and paths, parse to the IDE

```json
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/components/*": ["components/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

2. Aliases are configured in webpack.js

```js
// next.config.js
const path = require('path')
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
}

module.exports = {
  ...nextConfig,
  webpack: (config,
    { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, nextRuntime, webpack }) => {
    config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname),
      '@/components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'components'),
    }
    return config
  },
}
```

3. use

```
import Layout from '@/components/Layout'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely the https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias

It has nothing to do with NextJs.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts. the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

To set import aliases for components in your code, you can modify the "baseUrl" and "paths" configuration in your project's tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"]
    }
  }
}
```